# Any type of Animation or Timeline uses too much CPU in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm using JavaFx that comes with JDK 8.0, on a MacBook Pro with 2,4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor and 4GB of RAM.

I have a strange behavior, using the following class:

```
import com.sun.javafx.perf.PerformanceTracker;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    private static PerformanceTracker tracker;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        Scene scene= new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        Label label1 = new Label();
        Label label2 = new Label();
        ((Pane)root).getChildren().addAll(label1, label2);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed((e)->{
            label2.setText(label1.getText());
        });



        tracker = PerformanceTracker.getSceneTracker(scene);
        AnimationTimer frameRateMeter = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                label1.setText(String.format("Current frame rate: %.3f fps", getFPS()));
            }
        };

        //frameRateMeter.start();


    }

    private float getFPS () {
        float fps = tracker.getAverageFPS();
        tracker.resetAverageFPS();
        return fps;
    }
}
```

This code when executed uses CPU between a percentage of 0.2% to max 10%.
If I remove the comment from :

```
frameRateMeter.start();
```

I get that the same code uses CPU from 20% to 40%.

This is just an example but, the application I wrote,  commenting out the line above, runs using around 40% of CPU and removing the comment runs near 100% of CPU.

Is that normal? I notice that also adding any time of Timeline (also very simple one) that execute continuously, produces a ridiculous use of CPU.

Is really so expensive to use animation in JavaFX or there is something I have missed?

Any help would be really appreciate.

Comment: The code of Maxim's answer is a good solution . Using `com.sun....` seems risky for a future application cause the Library may be removed . You can use alternative ways to calculate frames per second , using 2 internal variables . BTW i will add an answer for that if you want.

Comment: Thank you @GOXR3PLUS, I would appreciate an answer for that. I have to underline also that using a timer or a timeline that are updated every 10 millisecond, increases the use of the CPU drastically. Maybe my machine is not the status of Art (Core 2 Duo with 4GB of Ram) but it should be able theoretically to manage this kind of operations easily, or not?

Comment: You should update your label every 1 second . No need of `Timeline` really... w8 The `AnimationTimer` is updated 60 times per Second ( actually it tries to do it).

Comment: Don't worry i will post an additional answer as soon as i get back to computer. Maybe in one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are updating FPS value in Label very frequently:

> The class AnimationTimer allows to create a timer, that is **called in each frame** while it is active.

When you update text in the `label1` the JavaFX draw new frames again and again. You can easy check this: write FPS to STDOUT instead of `label1`:

```
...
System.out.println(String.format("Current frame rate: %.3f fps", tracker.getAverageFPS()));
// label1.setText(String.format("Current frame rate: %.3f fps", tracker.getAverageFPS()));
...
```

In this case you should see less FPS rate.

So, try to update FPS value every one or half second use any Java/JavaFX timer i.e.:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), event -> {
    label1.setText(String.format("Current frame rate: %.3f fps", tracker.getAverageFPS()));
}));
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

Average CPU value is about 1.8-2% on my macOS.

Comment: Hi Maxim and Thank you for your reply, but what is the point in updating the FPS every second? FPS are the frames per second... Btw which Mac do you have?

Comment: The point is decrease CPU usage :) You should not to update text in label every millisecond because it increase CPU usage. Just update it once per second.

Comment: Hi Maxime, I get it now, and I have accepted you answer as correct. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to count **FPS**[frames per second] from `AnimationTimer` without using any other class:

```
/**
 * AnimationTimer .
 *
 * @author GOXR3PLUS
 */
public class PaintService extends AnimationTimer {

    /** The next second. */
    long nextSecond = 0L;

    /** The Constant ONE_SECOND_NANOS. */
    private static final long ONE_SECOND_NANOS = 1_000_000_000L;
    /**
     * When this property is <b>true</b> the AnimationTimer is running
     */
    private volatile SimpleBooleanProperty running = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);


    @Override
    public void start() {
        nextSecond = 0L;
        super.start();
        running.set(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        super.stop();
        running.set(false);
    }

    /**
     * @return True if AnimationTimer is running
     */
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running.get();
    }

    /**
     * @return Running Property
     */
    public SimpleBooleanProperty runningProperty() {
        return running;
    }


    @Override
    public void handle(long nanos) {

        // -- Show FPS if necessary.
        if (true) { //originally i had a variable (showFPS) here

            framesPerSecond++;

            // Check for 1 second passed
            if (nanos >= nextSecond) {
                fps = framesPerSecond;
                framesPerSecond = 0;
                nextSecond = nanos + ONE_SECOND_NANOS;
            }


            label.setText("FPS: " + fps);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: @navy1978 Nothing my friend... That's the code i use in my applications :)